# Secondary domain controller preparation failed

Tags: domain, domain-controller

I am getting the following error while creating a secondary domain controller.
My current domain controller is in Windows server 2012 and the functional level is 2003.
My new secondary Domain controller is in Windows server 2012 as well.
Could some please let me know how can I resolve this issue and create a secondary domain controller for our office network.

Verification of prerequisites for Active Directory preparation failed. Unable to verify whether schema master has completed a replication cycle after last reboot.
Exception: Unavailable Critical Extension. Server extended error: 8366. Server extended message: 000020AE: SvcErr: DSID-032103B4, problem 5010 (UNAVAIL_EXTENSION), data 8610
.
Adprep failed to verify whether schema master has completed a replication cycle after last reboot.
[Status/Consequence]
The schema is not upgraded.
[User Action]
Check the log file ADPrep.log in the C:\Windows\debug\adprep\logs\20200128104829-test directory for possible cause of failure.
Current Dc server is windows server 2012
Funtional level windows server 2003

Comment: What's in the ADPrep.log at the location given?

Comment: Adprep failed to verify whether schema master has completed a replication cycle after last reboot.

Comment: The schema is not upgraded.

Comment: Check the log file ADPrep.log in the C:\Windows\debug\adprep\logs\20200128121809-test directory for possible cause of failure.
[2020/01/28:12:18:09.829]
Adprep encountered an LDAP error.

Comment: Error code: 0xc. Server extended error code: 0x20ae, Server error message: 000020AE: SvcErr: DSID-032103B4, problem 5010 (UNAVAIL_EXTENSION), data 8610

Comment: DSID Info:
DSID: 0x180f0972
ldap error = 0xc
NT BUILD: 9600
NT BUILD: 16384

[2020/01/28:12:18:09.830]
Adprep successfully stopped using the specified credentials for network connections.